# Error 30034 on Trial Account - Can't Test SMS?

Tags: twilio, sms, trial

Got Error Code 30034 on a Trial Account 1 month into development.

[Error Code 30034](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8t3S.png)

Now we have to register our number in order to send SMS to US users but we are just sending to ourselves for testing.

[Can't have number during trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdozf.png)

[Registration pending, 2-3 week wait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgLvn.png)

Says can take up to 2-3 weeks for the 'campaign' to be registered.

How do you test this product? We used $1 of our trial and then where forced to basically register this number and can no longer test all our of our SMS points.

Does anyone know any work around for this? Is this standard?

--

All I can see is you verify your number and that should allow us to message or SMS to those numbers?

But I did this and got an error on our end, seeing if devs can troubleshoot.

I guess we just need to know if we 'verify' our phone number will we be able to send SMS as we await the number registration, etc?

Comment: If you send the same message again after getting the 30034 error, it may go through. Sometimes it takes multiple tries.